# Yii2 sorting indirectly related column which is not part of gridview model

Tags: gridview, yii

I have a gridview showing companies data. Every company has a tehsil_id as a foreign key. Below is the table structure from parent to child:

```
Country->province->city->district->tehsil
```

Every company is situated in a specific tehsil. A district or city or province can be traced using a tehsil ID backwards.

The problem I am facing is that I want to list companies which can be sorted by not only Tehsil ID (is a column in Company table) but also by City ID / Province ID / Country ID (None of these IDs are part of company table).

I am able to list these related district/city/province in gridview but not able to sort using these values. Your help will be appreciated.

```
<?php
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [

        'id',
        'name',
        // generated by schmunk42\giiant\crud\providers\RelationProvider::columnFormat
        [
            "class" => yii\grid\DataColumn::className(),
            "attribute" => "tehsil_id",
            'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Tehsil::find()->orderBy('name')->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
            "value" => function ($model) {
                if ($rel = $model->getTehsil()->one()) {
                    return yii\helpers\Html::a($rel->name, ["crud/tehsil/view", 'id' => $rel->id,], ["data-pjax" => 0]);
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            },
            "format" => "raw",
        ],

        [
            "class" => yii\grid\DataColumn::className(),
            "attribute" => "district_id",
            'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(District::find()->orderBy('name')->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
            "value" => function ($model) {
                if ($rel = $model->getTehsil()->one()->getDistrict()->one()) {
                    return yii\helpers\Html::a($rel->name, ["crud/district/view", 'id' => $rel->id,], ["data-pjax" => 0]);
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            },
            "format" => "raw",
        ],


        [
            "class" => yii\grid\DataColumn::className(),
            "attribute" => "city_id",
            'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(City::find()->orderBy('name')->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
            "value" => function ($model) {
                if ($rel = $model->getTehsil()->one()->getDistrict()->one()->getCity()->one()) {
                    return yii\helpers\Html::a($rel->name, ["crud/city/view", 'id' => $rel->id,], ["data-pjax" => 0]);
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            },
            "format" => "raw",
        ],
        // generated by schmunk42\giiant\crud\providers\RelationProvider::columnFormat
        [
            "class" => yii\grid\DataColumn::className(),
            "attribute" => "company_id",
            "value" => function ($model) {
                if ($rel = $model->getCompany()->one()) {
                    return yii\helpers\Html::a($rel->name, ["crud/company/view", 'id' => $rel->id,], ["data-pjax" => 0]);
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            },
            "format" => "raw",
        ],
        'phone',
        'fax',
        'mobile',
        'email:email',
        /*
        'created_on',
        'updated_on',
        'created_by',
        'updated_by',
        */
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
                // using the column name as key, not mapping to 'id' like the standard generator
                $params = is_array($key) ? $key : [$model->primaryKey()[0] => (string)$key];
                $params[0] = \Yii::$app->controller->id ? \Yii::$app->controller->id . '/' . $action : $action;
                return \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute($params);
            },
            'contentOptions' => ['nowrap' => 'nowrap']
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only sort on columns that are present in your original query. Most likely you have a `CompanySearch` class that has a `search()` method. In it, join more tables to your original query:

```
$query = Company::find()->joinWith([
    'tehsil',
    'tehsil.district',
    'tehsil.district.city',
    'tehsil.district.city.province',
    'tehsil.district.city.province.country'
]);
```

Then add your new columns to grid:

```
echo GridView::widget([
    ...
    'columns' => [
        'id',
        'name',
        'tehsil',
        'tehsil.district',
        'tehsil.district.city',
        'tehsil.district.city.province',
        'tehsil.district.city.province.country',
        ...
```

They should be sortable.

Also, check out this tutorial: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/